# ReferenceError: exports is not defined in babel compiling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs, ecmascript-5

I'm converting my reactjs file into es5 using online babel  [compiler](https://babeljs.io/repl) here is my file code

```
import React from 'react';

 class D1 extends React.Component {
constructor(){
    super()
    console.log("loaded D1 constructor")
}
render() {
    console.log("rendering D1")
    return (

        <div>
            D1 loaded from plugin by asad
        </div>

    );
}

 };

export default D1;
```

and the compiled code is this

```
"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
  });
 exports.default = void 0;

  var _react = _interopRequireDefault(require("react"));

    function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? 
     obj  
   : 
   { default: obj }; }

    function _instanceof(left, right) { if (right != null && typeof Symbol 
 !== "undefined" && right[Symbol.hasInstance]) { return 
   !!right[Symbol.hasInstance](left); } else { return left instanceof 
  right; 
  } }

   function _typeof(obj) { if (typeof Symbol === "function" && typeof 
    Symbol.iterator === "symbol") { _typeof = function _typeof(obj) { 
  return 
    typeof obj; }; } else { _typeof = function _typeof(obj) { return obj 
   && typeof Symbol === "function" && obj.constructor === Symbol && obj 
   !== Symbol.prototype ? "symbol" : typeof obj; }; } return _typeof(obj); 
}

  function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if 
  (!_instanceof(instance, Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call 
    a class as a function"); } }

 function _defineProperties(target, props) { for (var i = 0; i < 
    props.length; i++) { var descriptor = props[i]; descriptor.enumerable 
     = descriptor.enumerable || false; descriptor.configurable = true; if 
    ("value" in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true; 
      Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor); } }

        function _createClass(Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) { if 
       (protoProps) _defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps); 
       if (staticProps) _defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps); 
     return Constructor; }

 function _possibleConstructorReturn(self, call) { if (call && 
 (_typeof(call) 
 === "object" || typeof call === "function")) { return call; } return 
_assertThisInitialized(self); }

 function _assertThisInitialized(self) { if (self === void 0) { throw new 
   ReferenceError("this hasn't been initialised - super() hasn't been 
  called"); } 
  return self; }

     function _getPrototypeOf(o) { _getPrototypeOf = Object.setPrototypeOf 
  ? 
     Object.getPrototypeOf : function _getPrototypeOf(o) { return 
      o.__proto__ || 
     Object.getPrototypeOf(o); }; return _getPrototypeOf(o); }

  function _inherits(subClass, superClass) { if (typeof superClass !== 
   "function" && superClass !== null) { throw new TypeError("Super 
    expression 
  must either be null or a function"); } subClass.prototype = 
   Object.create(superClass && superClass.prototype, { constructor: { 
  value: 
  subClass, writable: true, configurable: true } }); if (superClass) 
 _setPrototypeOf(subClass, superClass); }

   function _setPrototypeOf(o, p) { _setPrototypeOf = 
 Object.setPrototypeOf || 
  function _setPrototypeOf(o, p) { o.__proto__ = p; return o; }; return 
    _setPrototypeOf(o, p); }

   var D1 =
  /*#__PURE__*/
  function (_React$Component) {
  _inherits(D1, _React$Component);

  function D1() {
   var _this;

_classCallCheck(this, D1);

    _this = _possibleConstructorReturn(this, 
_getPrototypeOf(D1).call(this));
    console.log("loaded D1 constructor");
    return _this;
   }

  _createClass(D1, [{
   key: "render",
   value: function render() {
    console.log("rendering D1");
     return _react.default.createElement("div", null, "D1 loaded from 
    plugin 
    by asad");
   }
  }]);

  return D1;
  }(_react.default.Component);

;
 var _default = D1;
    exports.default = _default;
```

but when I add this file in my code dynamically it gives me this error **exports is not defined** using this code

```
      fetch("/dist/D11.js")
        .then((resp) => { return resp.text()})
        .then((resp)=>{

            console.log(resp)
            let as=eval(resp).default;
            console.log(as)

        });
```

I have used to create-react-cli to create my main application. 
which is using webpack i think.